# Replacing the xml tags using xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to replace the entire Transaction(/DST/CDGCreateTree/DST/AWD/case/transaction) with another transaction tag as defined in X-path(/DST/CDGCreateTreeRequest/newNode/transaction)
and removing the element of (/DST/CDGCreateTreeRequest/newNode/transaction)

Can you please help me any one on this..

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
   <CDGCreateTree>
      <userID>%%%%%%</userID>
      <password>%%%%%</password>
      <hostAddress>%%%%%%%</hostAddress>
      <hostPort>12955</hostPort>
      <DST>
         <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
         <AWD>
            <case>
               <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
               <type>CALL</type>
               <status>CREATED</status>
               <recordType>C</recordType>
               <OUID>%%%%%%</OUID>
               <CKEY>2014012103.25.07.561840T01</CKEY>
               <PRVC>N</PRVC>
               <STRT>2014070700.28.41.043000</STRT>
               <STPT>2014070711.06.43.000000</STPT>
               <CMOO>Happy</CMOO>
               <CMED>Phone</CMED>
               <MLOB />
               <FDID>ANTHONY1900</FDID>
               <RMEM>ANTHONY1900</RMEM>
               <transaction>
                  <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
                  <type>ISSUE</type>
                  <status>CREATED</status>
                  <worklist>false</worklist>
                  <recordType>T</recordType>
                  <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                  <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
                  <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                  <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
                  <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
                  <ICT2>Adoption</ICT2>
                  <ICT3 />
                  <ICT4 />
                  <ICT5 />
                  <STRT>2014070710.59.00.000000</STRT>
                  <STPT>2014070711.04.09.000000</STPT>
                  <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                  <RGRP>JK212A0001</RGRP>
                  <RATH />
                  <RMEM>ANTHONY1900</RMEM>
                  <RPRV>JKCCRE</RPRV>
                  <RCLM />
                  <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
                  <MLOB>J9J8J701</MLOB>
                  <UIID>20140707110409DT77214</UIID>
                  <CBDS />
                  <CEDS />
                  <ABDS />
                  <AEDS />
                  <FDID>ANTHONY1900</FDID>
                  <comments>%%%%$%</comments>
               </transaction>
            </case>
         </AWD>
      </DST>
   </CDGCreateTree>
   <CDGCreateTreeRequest>
      <newNode>
         <transaction relate="Y" id="2014072100.50.35.618900T01">
            <id>2014072100.50.35.618900T01</id>
            <createTime time="Y">20140721T00:50:35:61890005:00</createTime>
            <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
            <type>ISSUE</type>
            <workStep status="TOVBR">VBR Labeling</workStep>
            <status>TOVBR</status>
            <queue>SYSTEM</queue>
            <priority>999</priority>
            <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
            <VIP>N</VIP>
            <assignedTo>SYSTEM</assignedTo>
            <lockedBy>SYSTEM</lockedBy>
            <amount>0.0000</amount>
            <amountType />
            <suspended>N</suspended>
            <process>Y</process>
            <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
            <iconName />
            <FDID>ANTHONY1900</FDID>
            <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
            <ICT2>Adoption</ICT2>
            <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
            <MLOB>J9J8J701</MLOB>
            <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
            <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
            <RGRP>JK212A0001</RGRP>
            <RMEM>ANTHONY1900</RMEM>
            <RPRV>JKCCRE</RPRV>
            <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
            <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
            <STPT>2014070711.04.09.000000</STPT>
            <STRT>2014070710.59.00.000000</STRT>
            <UIID>20140707110409DT77214</UIID>
            <CFLG>2</CFLG>
            <permission>Update</permission>
            <externalSystem>
               <host />
               <executable />
               <parameters />
               <procedure />
            </externalSystem>
            <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
         </transaction>
      </newNode>
   </CDGCreateTreeRequest>
</DST>


Expected xml:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
   <CDGCreateTree>
      <userID>%%%%%%</userID>
      <password>%%%%%</password>
      <hostAddress>%%%%%%%</hostAddress>
      <hostPort>12955</hostPort>
      <DST>
         <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
         <AWD>
            <case>
               <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
               <type>CALL</type>
               <status>CREATED</status>
               <recordType>C</recordType>
               <OUID>%%%%%%</OUID>
               <CKEY>2014012103.25.07.561840T01</CKEY>
               <PRVC>N</PRVC>
               <STRT>2014070700.28.41.043000</STRT>
               <STPT>2014070711.06.43.000000</STPT>
               <CMOO>Happy</CMOO>
               <CMED>Phone</CMED>
               <MLOB />
               <FDID>ANTHONY1900</FDID>
               <RMEM>ANTHONY1900</RMEM>
               <transaction relate="Y" id="2014072100.50.35.618900T01">
                <id>2014072100.50.35.618900T01</id>
                <createTime time="Y">20140721T00:50:35:61890005:00</createTime>
                <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
                <type>ISSUE</type>
                <workStep status="TOVBR">VBR Labeling</workStep>
                <status>TOVBR</status>
                <queue>SYSTEM</queue>
                <priority>999</priority>
                <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
                <VIP>N</VIP>
                <assignedTo>SYSTEM</assignedTo>
                <lockedBy>SYSTEM</lockedBy>
                <amount>0.0000</amount>
                <amountType />
                <suspended>N</suspended>
                <process>Y</process>
                <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
                <iconName />
                <FDID>ANTHONY1900</FDID>
                <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
                <ICT2>Adoption</ICT2>
                <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
                <MLOB>J9J8J701</MLOB>
                <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
                <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                <RGRP>JK212A0001</RGRP>
                <RMEM>ANTHONY1900</RMEM>
                <RPRV>JKCCRE</RPRV>
                <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
                <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                <STPT>2014070711.04.09.000000</STPT>
                <STRT>2014070710.59.00.000000</STRT>
                <UIID>20140707110409DT77214</UIID>
                <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                <permission>Update</permission>
                <externalSystem>
                   <host />
                   <executable />
                   <parameters />
                   <procedure />
                </externalSystem>
                <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
             </transaction>
            </case>
         </AWD>
      </DST>
   </CDGCreateTree>
   <CDGCreateTreeRequest>
      <newNode/>            
   </CDGCreateTreeRequest>
</DST>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="targetNode" select="DST/CDGCreateTreeRequest/newNode/transaction"/>

    <xsl:template match="transaction[not(ancestor::newNode)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$targetNode"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="transaction[ancestor::newNode]"/>

    <xsl:template match="newNode">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```